# U is not orthonormal in numpy.linalg.svd

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I would like to run svd in numpy on top of covariance matrix X_Conv,
I am using normalized data, where mean(X_Train_NN) = 0 and str(X_Train_NN) = 1.

The problem is that output U should be orthogonal matrix, but in my case it is not.
I will be very appreciate to you if you could help me with this problem. I am using python 3.

Please see code, X_Conv and output below:

```
import numpy as np

# calculate covariance matrix 
X_Conv = np.dot(X_Train_NN.T,X_Train_NN)/X_Train_NN.shape[0]

# logger: check that X_train_NN mean and std
mean_X = np.mean(X_Train_NN, axis = 0)
std_X = np.std(X_Train_NN, axis = 0)
logger.debug("mean_X = " + str(mean_X))
logger.debug(" std_X = " + str(std_X))

U, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(X_Conv, full_matrices=True)

logger.debug("checking column orthogonality U.TxU should be 1 = " +str(np.dot(U.T,U)))
```

Output of the code:

```
DEBUG:log:mean_X = [-2.76353840e-16  7.46632383e-15 -3.19430032e-18 -5.51256651e-14
  6.73173398e-14 -2.03904690e-16  1.13570028e-16  6.88569041e-16
 -1.44656294e-18 -1.28673525e-16 -1.24325432e-16  3.92298300e-15
  4.43334864e-14 -1.07224393e-14 -5.02879693e-14  2.24762293e-14
  2.01151862e-15  1.40932605e-15 -8.69219650e-16  5.75748493e-16
 -1.60788826e-15  3.80727360e-16 -1.95529529e-15]
DEBUG:log: std_X = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
DEBUG:log:checking column orthonormality U.TxU should be 1 = 
[[ 4.18986263e+01  7.78866230e+00 -3.79290892e+00  2.64551507e+00
   7.60034263e+00  5.17109180e+00  4.89345682e+00 -1.34036156e+00
  -7.35558093e-01  2.78281080e-01 -1.64138833e-01  4.80010113e-02
   1.67891076e-01  1.68355968e-01  1.24292601e-01 -2.78470152e-01
  -1.24036729e-01  1.45807249e-02  1.80634092e-02 -4.74034162e+00
  -2.00730944e-01  2.29647677e-02 -8.39858528e-02]
 [ 7.78866230e+00  2.46076833e+01 -2.05836929e+01 -8.42342426e+00
  -1.37713337e+01  5.89392478e+00  5.44139670e+00 -1.41706629e+00
   4.15925646e-02 -7.20330532e-01 -7.02911902e-01  3.66878928e-01
   2.32457934e-01  1.13897327e+00  4.13612576e-01 -4.72603209e-01
  -6.97982909e-02 -4.74574688e-02  4.56356236e-02 -6.48712811e+00
  -5.84864372e-01  2.05465983e-01 -5.83135789e-01]
 [-3.79290892e+00 -2.05836929e+01  3.51264286e+01  5.09734341e+00
   1.69702657e+01 -6.55508411e+00 -5.74440842e+00  1.30664168e+00
  -6.67623289e-01  9.76002446e-01  6.33001001e-01 -3.99895099e-01
  -2.88859409e-01 -9.07624814e-01 -3.05185635e-01  5.91870053e-01
   1.63647670e-01  3.44676130e-02 -4.07552237e-02  5.22792475e+00
   2.88943119e-01 -1.62837366e-01  1.98200221e-01]
.... so on
```

By request of tstanisl, I am adding output for X_Conv:

```
DEBUG:log:Covariance matrix X_Conv = 
[[ 1.00000000e+00  3.02089989e-01 -2.20564397e-04 -4.01385261e-02
  -3.59948781e-02  1.26225818e-02  1.09609529e-02  9.69523167e-03
   4.46336977e-03  2.25318391e-03  4.10303055e-03 -1.68605281e-02
  -3.12193965e-02 -1.99190837e-02  3.47434672e-02  6.64425293e-02
   8.65962962e-02 -6.50469786e-02 -1.52067215e-01 -1.56074981e-01
  -3.31018034e-02 -3.44282618e-02 -4.40141505e-02]
 [ 3.02089989e-01  1.00000000e+00 -5.91823453e-04 -2.14425301e-02
  -1.95802705e-02  7.34353709e-03  5.95945338e-03  4.84566442e-03
   3.87776698e-03 -9.20190459e-04  4.47932373e-03 -1.12435800e-02
  -1.57329528e-02 -6.72492601e-03  1.44564164e-02  2.34625673e-02
   3.08158565e-02 -2.85113114e-02 -5.66860797e-02 -5.06748101e-02
  -9.96534699e-03 -1.36737082e-02 -1.38159070e-02]
 [-2.20564397e-04 -5.91823453e-04  1.00000000e+00 -7.50018621e-03
  -6.35811454e-03  1.34526568e-03  1.12611474e-03  1.35733227e-03
  -2.05308203e-03 -2.28860577e-03  1.85466397e-03 -5.38568391e-04
   9.69423074e-04 -1.46555576e-04  8.03096569e-03  1.49348551e-03
  -3.99493083e-04 -3.81117273e-03  1.50096415e-03  8.19227308e-04
   1.38602766e-03  5.10227665e-03  2.15772478e-04]
 [-4.01385261e-02 -2.14425301e-02 -7.50018621e-03  1.00000000e+00
   7.35383768e-01  3.20972531e-03  2.62639318e-03  2.33713035e-03
  -2.08289867e-04 -4.27977413e-04 -6.71804119e-04  5.15055106e-02
   7.79352705e-02  6.35683260e-02 -3.39995153e-02 -1.29255566e-02
  -8.89831901e-03  4.71151984e-02  8.67077174e-02  6.51201759e-02
   7.78731430e-03  3.31610813e-02  2.97222675e-02]
 [-3.59948781e-02 -1.95802705e-02 -6.35811454e-03  7.35383768e-01
   1.00000000e+00  5.61625650e-03  5.76250245e-03  4.71010406e-03
   1.79130794e-03 -8.64162093e-04 -5.97111694e-04  7.50630309e-02
   1.02162733e-01  9.60308985e-02 -3.40988414e-02  1.04144776e-03
  -1.78422499e-02  6.50241947e-02  7.30211112e-02  1.27326759e-01
   8.75515969e-03  2.65665749e-02  4.81802315e-02]
 [ 1.26225818e-02  7.34353709e-03  1.34526568e-03  3.20972531e-03
   5.61625650e-03  1.00000000e+00  8.42834887e-01  7.77146911e-01
   4.28802294e-03 -9.77371115e-04 -2.69449719e-03  4.85308069e-03
   6.57254655e-03  1.02355188e-02  2.86325791e-03  7.51758347e-03
   7.49105474e-03 -1.17195032e-03 -1.87705728e-03  5.15072876e-03
  -1.14221858e-02 -8.89798975e-03 -8.57906279e-03]
 [ 1.09609529e-02  5.95945338e-03  1.12611474e-03  2.62639318e-03
   5.76250245e-03  8.42834887e-01  1.00000000e+00  7.25841236e-01
   2.47512434e-03  6.97891550e-04 -2.56070982e-03  4.43590864e-03
   7.51951326e-03  8.08540555e-03  2.99621861e-03  6.65534177e-03
   6.15357341e-03  1.01712549e-04 -1.78005661e-03  4.36052134e-03
  -8.52819682e-03 -9.74229068e-03 -9.24943243e-03]
 [ 9.69523167e-03  4.84566442e-03  1.35733227e-03  2.33713035e-03
   4.71010406e-03  7.77146911e-01  7.25841236e-01  1.00000000e+00
   1.61625236e-03 -1.93268068e-03  3.34723151e-03  3.44022916e-03
   6.41874747e-03  1.03195975e-02  2.30470154e-03  7.45833141e-03
   8.87504270e-03  1.62827852e-04 -1.44817653e-03  3.51559085e-03
  -6.91035538e-03 -9.08540883e-03 -1.26132002e-02]
 [ 4.46336977e-03  3.87776698e-03 -2.05308203e-03 -2.08289867e-04
   1.79130794e-03  4.28802294e-03  2.47512434e-03  1.61625236e-03
   1.00000000e+00  3.21693073e-01  2.69527979e-01 -5.75473985e-03
  -4.69916238e-03 -3.88573129e-03  5.21097576e-03 -1.56165910e-04
   6.61499655e-04 -5.66347244e-03 -1.30169931e-03 -3.11642901e-03
   4.13166400e-03 -3.88339483e-03 -4.53536735e-03]
 [ 2.25318391e-03 -9.20190459e-04 -2.28860577e-03 -4.27977413e-04
  -8.64162093e-04 -9.77371115e-04  6.97891550e-04 -1.93268068e-03
   3.21693073e-01  1.00000000e+00  1.75799416e-01 -2.02156365e-03
  -4.89921537e-03 -2.38795147e-03  4.60064401e-03  1.90201195e-03
   1.12669703e-03 -1.53644506e-03 -3.99449175e-03 -6.43884999e-04
   9.17031435e-04 -8.84794620e-04 -5.90454057e-04]
 [ 4.10303055e-03  4.47932373e-03  1.85466397e-03 -6.71804119e-04
  -5.97111694e-04 -2.69449719e-03 -2.56070982e-03  3.34723151e-03
   2.69527979e-01  1.75799416e-01  1.00000000e+00 -3.03114692e-03
  -2.43439638e-03 -4.15970468e-03  1.14023012e-03  1.63101190e-03
   2.72785293e-03 -1.46918713e-03 -8.77113853e-04 -3.78019621e-03
   3.69107579e-03  1.51041020e-03 -6.18612712e-03]
 [-1.68605281e-02 -1.12435800e-02 -5.38568391e-04  5.15055106e-02
   7.50630309e-02  4.85308069e-03  4.43590864e-03  3.44022916e-03
  -5.75473985e-03 -2.02156365e-03 -3.03114692e-03  1.00000000e+00
   1.41408810e-01  1.15710164e-01  4.02466794e-01 -2.90897360e-03
   1.31912491e-03  7.00524183e-01  8.04244270e-02  6.46250124e-02
  -4.58252278e-03  1.73501498e-02  1.16613315e-02]
 [-3.12193965e-02 -1.57329528e-02  9.69423074e-04  7.79352705e-02
   1.02162733e-01  6.57254655e-03  7.51951326e-03  6.41874747e-03
  -4.69916238e-03 -4.89921537e-03 -2.43439638e-03  1.41408810e-01
   1.00000000e+00  9.94343481e-02 -4.64660636e-02  5.55168492e-01
   1.87992792e-03  1.42145278e-01  6.32188235e-01  6.13452373e-02
   2.26157209e-02  1.86102956e-02  1.53425580e-02]
 [-1.99190837e-02 -6.72492601e-03 -1.46555576e-04  6.35683260e-02
   9.60308985e-02  1.02355188e-02  8.08540555e-03  1.03195975e-02
  -3.88573129e-03 -2.38795147e-03 -4.15970468e-03  1.15710164e-01
   9.94343481e-02  1.00000000e+00 -3.97634410e-02 -1.67927421e-03
   5.93912228e-01  1.20039339e-01  6.21726352e-02  6.18702931e-01
   1.40252646e-02  1.30026073e-02  5.50682701e-02]
 [ 3.47434672e-02  1.44564164e-02  8.03096569e-03 -3.39995153e-02
  -3.40988414e-02  2.86325791e-03  2.99621861e-03  2.30470154e-03
   5.21097576e-03  4.60064401e-03  1.14023012e-03  4.02466794e-01
  -4.64660636e-02 -3.97634410e-02  1.00000000e+00  8.60397087e-03
   5.98846606e-03 -1.39966984e-01 -3.63693895e-02 -2.81822000e-02
  -2.34349286e-02 -7.11435995e-03 -7.85019522e-03]
 [ 6.64425293e-02  2.34625673e-02  1.49348551e-03 -1.29255566e-02
   1.04144776e-03  7.51758347e-03  6.65534177e-03  7.45833141e-03
  -1.56165910e-04  1.90201195e-03  1.63101190e-03 -2.90897360e-03
   5.55168492e-01 -1.67927421e-03  8.60397087e-03  1.00000000e+00
   1.59936957e-02 -1.00853064e-02 -5.01769228e-02 -2.57944901e-02
  -4.77212451e-03 -3.21818378e-02 -1.16145776e-02]
 [ 8.65962962e-02  3.08158565e-02 -3.99493083e-04 -8.89831901e-03
  -1.78422499e-02  7.49105474e-03  6.15357341e-03  8.87504270e-03
   6.61499655e-04  1.12669703e-03  2.72785293e-03  1.31912491e-03
   1.87992792e-03  5.93912228e-01  5.98846606e-03  1.59936957e-02
   1.00000000e+00 -7.09205862e-03 -2.30158592e-02 -5.61838035e-02
  -1.27232331e-02 -1.03198785e-02 -2.79517721e-02]
 [-6.50469786e-02 -2.85113114e-02 -3.81117273e-03  4.71151984e-02
   6.50241947e-02 -1.17195032e-03  1.01712549e-04  1.62827852e-04
  -5.66347244e-03 -1.53644506e-03 -1.46918713e-03  7.00524183e-01
   1.42145278e-01  1.20039339e-01 -1.39966984e-01 -1.00853064e-02
  -7.09205862e-03  1.00000000e+00  1.02712283e-01  7.63312088e-02
   2.30125600e-02  1.96614329e-02  1.52265783e-02]
 [-1.52067215e-01 -5.66860797e-02  1.50096415e-03  8.67077174e-02
   7.30211112e-02 -1.87705728e-03 -1.78005661e-03 -1.44817653e-03
  -1.30169931e-03 -3.99449175e-03 -8.77113853e-04  8.04244270e-02
   6.32188235e-01  6.21726352e-02 -3.63693895e-02 -5.01769228e-02
  -2.30158592e-02  1.02712283e-01  1.00000000e+00  9.26362846e-02
   3.13199876e-02  6.67561217e-02  3.61587860e-02]
 [-1.56074981e-01 -5.06748101e-02  8.19227308e-04  6.51201759e-02
   1.27326759e-01  5.15072876e-03  4.36052134e-03  3.51559085e-03
  -3.11642901e-03 -6.43884999e-04 -3.78019621e-03  6.46250124e-02
   6.13452373e-02  6.18702931e-01 -2.81822000e-02 -2.57944901e-02
  -5.61838035e-02  7.63312088e-02  9.26362846e-02  1.00000000e+00
   2.56450361e-02  2.88101041e-02  1.22801153e-01]
 [-3.31018034e-02 -9.96534699e-03  1.38602766e-03  7.78731430e-03
   8.75515969e-03 -1.14221858e-02 -8.52819682e-03 -6.91035538e-03
   4.13166400e-03  9.17031435e-04  3.69107579e-03 -4.58252278e-03
   2.26157209e-02  1.40252646e-02 -2.34349286e-02 -4.77212451e-03
  -1.27232331e-02  2.30125600e-02  3.13199876e-02  2.56450361e-02
   1.00000000e+00  6.55756070e-02  4.75197713e-02]
 [-3.44282618e-02 -1.36737082e-02  5.10227665e-03  3.31610813e-02
   2.65665749e-02 -8.89798975e-03 -9.74229068e-03 -9.08540883e-03
  -3.88339483e-03 -8.84794620e-04  1.51041020e-03  1.73501498e-02
   1.86102956e-02  1.30026073e-02 -7.11435995e-03 -3.21818378e-02
  -1.03198785e-02  1.96614329e-02  6.67561217e-02  2.88101041e-02
   6.55756070e-02  1.00000000e+00  4.63450303e-02]
 [-4.40141505e-02 -1.38159070e-02  2.15772478e-04  2.97222675e-02
   4.81802315e-02 -8.57906279e-03 -9.24943243e-03 -1.26132002e-02
  -4.53536735e-03 -5.90454057e-04 -6.18612712e-03  1.16613315e-02
   1.53425580e-02  5.50682701e-02 -7.85019522e-03 -1.16145776e-02
  -2.79517721e-02  1.52265783e-02  3.61587860e-02  1.22801153e-01
   4.75197713e-02  4.63450303e-02  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: what is `np.linalg.cond(X_Conv)`?

Comment: np.linalg.cond(X_Conv) = 407.2211316398458

Comment: how large is X_Conv? I mean `X_Conv.shape`? Is it as small as in output example?

Comment: shape of X_Conv is (23,23)

Comment: Try to put `X_conv` to the question

Comment: I didn't understand a question. What should I do with X_Conv?

Comment: `X_Conv` is small. `U` depends only on `X_Conv`. So paste `X_Conv` to the question so other could reproduce the error.

Comment: I have updated question and add X_Conv in it

Comment: For matrix in the question `np.isclose(np.dot(U.T, U), np.eye(23)).all()` returned true. So the error is not in SVD itself

Comment: this is strange, for me return false: DEBUG:log:np.isclose(np.dot(U.T, U), np.eye(23)).all() = False

Comment: `np.linalg.cond(X_Conv)` of the matrix in the answer is 25.67, not 407.22. Are you sure that it is the same matrix?

Comment: Dear tstanisl, I have tried to insert X_Conv by copying, what I published (so no calculation from X_Train_NN), but I still have the same result of non-orthonormal matirx. Could be it my environment, that for some reason svd doesn't work properly for me?

Comment: Yes, even with copied X_Conv, it gives me: DEBUG:log:np.linalg.cond(X_Conv) = 407.2211271570804    Looks like np.linalg doesn't work for me properly

Comment: Dear tstanisl, I have copied code to another notebook with python 2 (originally I am using python 3) and it works as expected: ``` np.linalg.cond(X_Conv) = 25.673797675020783
np.isclose(np.dot(U.T, U), np.eye(23)).all() = True ``` Looks like it is environment problem, but do you have idea how to fix it or I have to contact experts, who support this enviroment?

Comment: Dear tstanisl, thank you a lot for helping debug this issue. Finally, it was a configuration problem. I have reset all environment and mistake is disappeared. I have contacted to support team, who is responsible for the cluster, where I am working and they looking in such strange bug...  Without you, I never understand that it is not a coding mistake. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad I could help